# SQL Server- if else/case when statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, if-statement, sql-server-2012, case-when

I wrote a case statement in my select query as follows. I am not sure about the syntax for If else in SQL Server and also I want to name the column using 'as' but it's throwing error saying wrong syntax near 'as'. Please help. T

```
select 
    a.account_id as [Account Id],
    substring(a.account_id,1,3) as [Company ID],
    substring(a.account_id,4,6) as [Account No],
    substring(a.account_id,10,5) as [Cost Center],
    b.amount as Amount,
    b.period as Period,
    getdate() as SysDate,
    format(getdate(), 'mm/dd/yyyy') as SYSDtText,
    substring('SYSDtText',1,2) as [Current Period],
    b.year_budget as [Year Budget],
    substring('SYSDtText', 7, 4 ) as SysDtYearText,
    case 
       when Period <= 'Current Period' 
          then 'include' 
          else '' 
    as [Period Include Flag], 
    a.description as [Description]
from 
    period_summary b
inner join 
    account a on b.account_id = a.account_id;
```

Comment: you missed `end`  between `else ''` and `as`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to change this line:

```
CASE WHEN Period<='Current Period' then 'include' else '' as [Period Include Flag],
```

to this:

```
CASE WHEN Period <= substring('SYSDtText',1,2) then 'include' else '' end as [Period Include Flag],
```

Currently you are comparing [Period] to a string literal 'Current Period' -- I don't think this is what you intend to do as there is a column in your query called [Current Period].

Answer (score 2):

You are missing an "end"

Correct:

```
CASE WHEN Period<='Current Period' then 'include' else '' end as [Period Include Flag]
```

Comment: Worked. Thanks a lot!